# How to make SSR with QuasarFramework work and why is "preFetch" not executed?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I tried to make the **Quasar**-Skeleton-App run using **SSR**. I set up the Quasar skeleton with using TypeScript and **Vite**.

I have enabled SSR in Quasar and implemented a `preFetch`-Method in a component. It won't be executed, the rendering happens client-side and I have no chance to preFetch information.

So I miss particular things here that seem to be not well documented.

What did I wrong?

quasar.config.js:

```
    preFetch: true,
    ssr: {
      pwa: false,
      prodPort: 3000, // The default port that the production server should use
      middlewares: [
        'render', // keep this as last one
      ],
    },
```

The ExampleComponent.vue contains a `preFetch`-function, which only `console.log` something, which never happens.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, PropType, computed, ref, toRef, Ref } from 'vue';
import { Todo, Meta } from './models';

function useClickCount() {
  const clickCount = ref(0);
  function increment() {
    clickCount.value += 1;
    return clickCount.value;
  }

  return { clickCount, increment };
}

function useDisplayTodo(todos: Ref<Todo[]>) {
  const todoCount = computed(() => todos.value.length);
  return { todoCount };
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    todos: {
      type: Array as PropType<Todo[]>,
      default: () => [],
    },
    meta: {
      type: Object as PropType<Meta>,
      required: true,
    },
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
  },

  preFetch({
    store,
    currentRoute,
    previousRoute,
    redirect,
    ssrContext,
    urlPath,
    publicPath,
  }) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('preFetch', {
      store,
      currentRoute,
      previousRoute,
      redirect,
      ssrContext,
      urlPath,
      publicPath,
    });
  },

  setup(props) {
    return { ...useClickCount(), ...useDisplayTodo(toRef(props, 'todos')) };
  },
});
</script>
```

What is missing? How to make SSR work with Quasar?

Answer (score 2):

I found out, that only in Vue-components using the  `export default { }`-syntax, the **prefetching** works:

This example works in my test application:

## OK-Example: preFetch will be executed

```
<template>
  <div>{{ item }}</div>
</template>

<script>

import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  // our hook here
  preFetch ({ store, currentRoute, previousRoute, redirect, ssrContext, urlPath, publicPath }) {
    console.log("***** PREFETCH *****")
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // some async task
        console.log("***** PREFETCH READY *****");
        resolve()
      }, 1000)
    });
  },

  setup () {
    const item = ref('aaa')
    return { item }
  }
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work here:

## 2. Example: preFetch will never get executed

```
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue';

// Define reactive properties directly
const item = ref('aaa');

// Define the preFetch hook as a normal function
const preFetch = ({ store, currentRoute, previousRoute, redirect, ssrContext, urlPath, publicPath }) => {
  console.log("***** PREFETCH *****");

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // some async task
      console.log("***** PREFETCH READY *****");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
};

// Expose any necessary properties or methods
defineExpose({
  item,
  preFetch
});

</script>
```

And using defineComponent will also lead to preFetch never getting executed:

## 3. Example: preFetch gets never executed

```
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent, ref} from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'TestComponent',
  components: {},
  methods: {},
  props: {},


  preFetch ({ store, currentRoute, previousRoute, redirect, ssrContext, urlPath, publicPath }) {
    // fetch data, validate route and optionally redirect to some other route...
    console.log("PREFTETCH")
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // some async task
        console.log("READY");
        resolve()
      }, 1000)
    })
  },

  setup() {
    const data = ref('loading...');
    return {data};
  },
});
</script>
```